# How Can I Enable Remote Access To Localhost Subfolders?

Tags: localhost, wamp, hosting

I am trying to set up a website on my localhost using WAMPServer and Pktriot. I have built the website in the localhost subfolder C:\wamp64\www\mywebsite on a virtual server and have set up a tunnel between my pktriot domain and the localhost. However, when I try to set up the tunnel between my pktriot domain and the localhost subfolder above, I get a 403 error.

I have configured httpd-vhosts.conf as follows:

```
# Virtual Hosts
 #
  <VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>"
```

In addition to this I have set up httpd.conf like this:

```
<Directory /> 
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews
AllowOverride All 
Order allow,deny 
Allow from all 
</Directory>
```

I have set up my hosts file like this:

```
#
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost
```

I have port forwarded port 80 on my router and have added a firewall exception for port 80.

What am I missing here? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Best regards,
Samuel